# PowerShell looking for duplicated processes

Tags: powershell, process, wmi

This code does work..  However, I am not able to determine if it is Notepad.exe or TextPad.exe..  The $a.Name variable is not working..

```
$log = "D:\WORK\ps\duplicate.txt"
If (test-path -path $log) {
Remove-Item $log
}

##$query = "Select * from win32_Process where name like '%script%'"
$query = "Select * from win32_Process where name like '%pad%'"

#$a = Get-WmiObject -Query $query | select name, processID | sort name

$SERVERS = get-content -Path D:\WORK\ps\monitored_computers.txt
$(Foreach ($server in $SERVERS) {
    $a = Get-WmiObject -Query $query -ComputerName $server | select name, processID | sort name
    IF ($a.Count -gt 1 ) { $server + " count: " + $a.Count + " name: " + $a.name | Out-File -append -filepath $log -encoding ASCII }
})

If (test-path -path $log) {
    send-mailmessage -from "sender@company.com" -to "receiver@company.com" -subject "Duplicated processes" -body "Please see attached"  -Attachment $log -dno onSuccess, onFailure -smtpServer smpthost.company.com
}
```

Comment: Could you give a little more detail as to what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am setting up a monitor (Scheduled Task) to let us know if we have any hung or stuck Wscript/Cscript processes..  I have already done it under VBScript..

Answer (score 2):

`$a` is an array when `Get-WmiObject` returns more than 1 result. While the array *elements* have a `Name` property, the array itself does not. You need PowerShell v3 or newer if you want to be able to access element properties directly from an array variable.

PowerShell v2:

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1

PS C:\> $qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name LIKE '%pad%'"
PS C:\> $a = gwmi -Query $qry | select Name, ProcessId
PS C:\> $a.Name
PS C:\> $a | ft -Auto

Name        ProcessId
----        ---------
notepad.exe      1812
notepad.exe      1728
```

PowerShell v3:

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
3      0      -1     -1

PS C:\> $qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name LIKE '%pad%'"
PS C:\> $a = gwmi -Query $qry | select Name, ProcessId
PS C:\> $a.Name
notepad.exe
notepad.exe
PS C:\> $a | ft -Auto

Name        ProcessId
----        ---------
notepad.exe      3460
notepad.exe      3580
```

On PowerShell v2 or earlier you need to get the individual array element if you want to access on of its properties:

```
PS C:\> $a[0].Name
notepad.exe
```

or you could select/expand the property:

```
PS C:\> $a | select -Expand Name
notepad.exe
notepad.exe
```

However, it's not quite clear to me what your desired output is. Do you want the names of all *pad executables (e.g. `Notepad.exe Notepad.exe Textpad.exe Notepad.exe`)? Just the unique names (`Notepad.exe Textpad.exe`)? The number of each pad type (`3 Notepad.exe, 1 Textpad.exe`)? Something else?

Also, `$a` isn't guaranteed to be an array. Depending on what `Get-WmiObject` returns it could also be a single object (without a `Count` property) or `$null` (no results). Better change

```
if ( $a.Count -gt 1 ) { ... }
```

into

```
if ( @($a).Count -gt 1 ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ansgar Wiechers explained it perfectly.
You can also use Foreach-object to achieve this.

```
IF ($a.Count -ge 1 ) { $a | foreach-object {" count: " + $a.Count + " name: " + $_.name| Out-File -append -filepath $log -encoding ASCII }}
```